# Cursor in my simpleform input area appears not in the top left

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, simple-form, form-helpers

[image]

I have not determined how to get my cursor to appear in the top left of my message field.

I added a class of 'span3' to the message field so I could manipulate the css (template and css below)

```
<%= simple_form_for @guestbook, url: guestbooks_path, method: :post do |f| %>
    <%= f.input :name %>
    <%= f.input :email %>
    <%= f.input :message, input_html: { class: 'span1' } %>
    <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>

.span1 {
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

the display: inline-block just moved the message text right next to the input area.

Any ideas on how I should deal with this problem?

Answer (score 0):

[Simple Form on GitHub](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form). It looks like `input :text` is the way to create a `textarea` with Simple Forms. I don't see a `:message` on the list of generated HTML elements.

It's most likely appearing in the center because you've created an `input` element, which only allows for a single line of content, as opposed to a `textarea`, which is a block-level element.

Comment: I'm looking at the document, I tried changing my form helper to f.textarea, which returned an undefined method error. I then tried f.text and got the same error

Comment: That also did not work, but I ultimately got it going with, <%= f.input :message, as: :text, input_html: { class: 'span1' } %>